# Is $q^m\equiv 1~{\rm mod~4}$ for $m$ is even and $q$ a power of a odd prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

When $m$ is an even integer and $q$ a power of a odd prime, do we have $q^m\equiv 1~{\rm mod~4}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

By Euler's Theorem, for each odd prime $ p $, we have

$$p^2 \equiv 1 \;\mod 4$$

because

$$gcd(p,4)=1$$
and
$$\phi(4)= \# \{1,3\}=2$$

So, apply with $$q=p^n \;  \text{ and }\;  m=2k$$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

For $q=p^k,\ m=2n$ we get $q^m=p^{2nk}$. For all odd primes, $p\equiv \pm1 \bmod 4$.

Substituting, $q^m\equiv (\pm 1)^{2nk}=((\pm 1)^2)^{nk}=1^{nk}=1 \bmod 4$

The answer to your question is yes.

Comment: Thank you very much!